# Best way of updating Recyclerview data

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I am currently learning about recyclerview and writing a code using this tutorial 
http://wiseassblog.com/2016/06/22/android-recyclerview-tutorial-onclick-and-design-part-3b/

In the tutorial the guy says that the way he presented of updating the recyclerview data is not good for programs that takes data from internet data bases and that's what I need it to do..

So I wanted to ask you what is the best way of doing it in order of the program will work well?

the current code is:

```
@Override

    public void onSecondaryIconClick(int p) {

        ListItem item = (ListItem) listData.get(p);

        //update our data

        if (item.isFavourite()){

            item.setFavourite(false);

        } else {

            item.setFavourite(true);

        }

        //pass new data to adapter and update

        adapter.setListData(listData);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

and on the adapter:

```
public void setListData(ArrayList<ListItem> exerciseList) {

    this.listData.clear();

    this.listData.addAll(exerciseList);

}
```

Comment: It depends on requirements. If you are working on making like/favorite which will be stored locally you can use this way. Besides, working completely on Web Service which will keep your favorites, you need to update it simultaneously. Best Practice can be clone the data from Web make whatever changes you want and Update the server onPause. This way you can avoid keep refreshing Recycler View which is costly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like clicking on the secondary icon is intended to: 1) toggle the value of whether that item is a favorite  and then 2) change the display of that item to indicate favoritism.
So you would not want to rebuild the entire list at that point.
You should be able to replace:

```
    //pass new data to adapter and update

    adapter.setListData(listData);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with

```
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(p);
```

to update just that one item in the adapter.